# How does the bootloader choose dtb overlay?

Tags: bootloader, device-tree

I'm examining the dtb (device tree blob) files of a stock Android rom. After Android 10, the base dtb resides in `vendor_boot.img` and the dtb overlay reside in `dtbo.img`.

I successfully:

- unpacked android roms, got `vendor_boot.img` and `dtbo.img`;
- used `extract-dtb` to extract dtb files from those *.img files.

Finally I found there are multiple dtb overlays extracted from one dtbo.img.
For example, Pixel 6a has 10 dtb overlays:

```
$ ls
01_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
02_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
03_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
04_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
05_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
06_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
07_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
08_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
09_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
10_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb
```

My questions are:

- How does the bootloader know which dtb overlay file it should select?
- Does the bootloader simply choose all dtb overlays and apply them to the base dtb?
- Are the dtb selecting commands hard-coded into the bootloader?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answers to your questions are typically implementation specific.  IOW your questions are too vague.

Comment: Thank you sawdust. I found [this post](https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/dto/multiple) and it seems that the bootloader selects the dtb overlay basing on the board type.

Comment: The Device Tree describes the hardware, and is used to install the proper device drivers and provide configuration parameters. So the DT handed to the kernel must match the board. The ambiguous part of that web article is "identify hardware and load one .dtb." So how do you "identify hardware"? That's the implementation specific aspect I was referring to. Some boards have jumpers or EEPROM or other HW to self-identify the board to the boot program. Or environment variables might be used to define the HW. It's a chicken vs egg problem that the boot program has to resolve for the kernel.

Comment: Thank you sawdust. Actually I am exploring the possible combination of DTB overlays that may be applied to the dtb base. 

For example in our case, the bootloader may choose `01_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb` and `03_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb` to overly dtb base for the board A, while choose `02_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb` and `04_dtbdump_fragment@0.dtb` for the board B.

However, iterating all the possible combinations is tedious and unnecessary, I prefer to find and extract the possible `if...else` like commands from the bootloader to get all the combinations and reduce manual efforts.

Comment: I tried to compare the model property between the dtb base and dtb overlays to choose proper dtb overlays, but the model strings don't match. Do you have any suggestion or insight about how to get the possible cominations of dtb overlays? Thank you again!

Comment: The "*possible cominations of dtb overlays*" are irrelevant. Presumably the overlays can be grouped by HW functionality. Perhaps there are overlays for different screens, alternate touch sensors, and other optional peripherals. Only one overlay for a screen has to be loaded; only one overlay for a touch sensor has to be loaded.  The selections are based on however the boot program determines what the actual hardware is. That is implementation specific. Read my first comment again. Then read it again until you understand it.